# Reverse engineering a differential equation from singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, sagemath

I've been struggling to find a way to reverse engineer a differential equation based on knowing it's singular points. In this case, I'd like to create a flow on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, which has saddles at (0,1/4) and (0/-1/4), with a source at (0,1/2), and a sink at (0,-1/2). It should also be vertical on the boundary.

I've been starting with the assumption that I need a system of ODEs, $\stackrel{.}{x} = f(x,y)$ and $\stackrel{.}{y} = g(x,y)$, where $f$ and $g$ are both zero at each of the points, and that the Jacobian would give me 4 conditions on the partial derivatives, but I seem to have too much data to make sense of this. Even when I think I have it for just one of the points, I have Sage graph it, and it's wrong.

Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: if you have a center at $(0,0)$  it seems possible. i have a hunch that as it is you cannot have a flow with two saddles, sink  and a source. i don't have a firm reason for it.

Comment: The paper I'm working through has a drawing of a flow with these points, but all it says is "It is clear they exist". Here's the link on JSTOR, it's Figure 1 - http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970458?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be an example:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x
= \left( {x}^{2}-1 \right)  \left( {y}^{2}-1 \right) xy,
\\
\dot y
= \left( {x}^{2}+ \left( y-3/8 \right) ^{2}-{\frac {1}{64}} \right) 
  \left( {x}^{2}+ \left( y+3/8 \right) ^{2}-{\frac {1}{64}} \right).
\end{array}
$$
Here plotted with vectors scaled for visual clarity.
[image: Flow lines]

The way I found it was by drawing the flow lines, then determining where $\dot x=0$ and where $\dot y=0$, where I could choose nice shapes like lines and circles for these zero sets, and then select the right sign to use.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!